# jQuery setting value of a session

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I want to change the value of a cookie once a dropdown change event is triggered.

I have an mvc application with the following code on base controller:

```
public class CustomController : Controller
{
    HttpCookie mYcookie = new HttpCookie("trycookie");
    HttpCookie cookieCounter = new HttpCookie("cookieCounter");

    protected override void OnActionExecuted()
    {
        if (cookieCounter.Value == null)
        {
            mYcookie.Value = "tryvalue";

        // do something here //
        }
    }
}
```

What it do is create an instance of a cookie once the application run. Then I have a jquery to manipulate the cookie:

```
$.cookie("mYcookie", "tryvaluehere");
$.cookie("cookieCounter", "tryvaluehereagain");
```

My problem here whenever I debug on my c# code, the value of my cookies are " ". But whenever I tried to alert the cookie on that same jquery code, I get the value I wanted

```
alert($.cookie("mYcookie"));
```

Is my `HttpCookie` instance being created again even if I declare them outside my method? Any suggestions will gladly be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What I did is create an instance of the cookie from the request. If the request is null, create that cookie as a new cookie.

```
public class CustomController : Controller
{
    HttpCookie mYcookie = this.Request.Cookies["trycookie"];
    HttpCookie cookieCounter = this.Request.Cookies["trycookie"];

    protected override void OnActionExecuted()
    {
        if (cookieCounter == null)
        {
            mYcookie = new HttpCookie("somenamehere");
        }
        else
        {
        // do something here //
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read the cookie from the request:

```
public class CustomController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuted()
    {
        HttpCookie myCookie = this.Request.Cookies["trycookie"];
        HttpCookie cookieCounter = this.Request.Cookies["cookieCounter"];

        if (cookieCounter != null)
        {
            // do something here //
        }
    }
}
```

or if you want to set a cookie then create a new instance of the cookie and add it to the response:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("name", "some value");
this.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Comment: I did the `this.Request.Cookies` but they are null. I believe because this is the first run of code because the user has not triggered an event on the client side.

Comment: Yes, that's perfectly normal. `this.Request.Cookies["trycookie"]` will have a value one there's a cookie being sent in the request. If you are setting the cookie in javascript then it's perfectly normal that on the first request there won't be any.

Comment: How am I going to make this `cookie` available on the first run?

Comment: You can't. This doesn't make any sense. The browser will not send any cookie until you set this cookie. You could set the cookie either on the server (by adding it to the Response.Cookies collection as shown in my answer) or on the client. The cookie will be available on all subsequent requests to the server. I would recommend you reading a little more about what a cookie is and how they work: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie

Comment: Yes, that is what i'm doing. Create an instance on the server then wait for the client to change the value of that cookies. Its just that I can't get the response of the cookies after the user triggered the event.

Comment: Once you modify the value of the cookie on the client, **on subsequent requests** to the server you will be able to get the updated cookie value by reading it from the `Request.Cookies["cookie_name"]`.

Comment: Thanks Darin! You helped me solve my answer. Please see my answer.